# Backbonejs view with jQuery for Dynamic form - listeners being replicated as user navigates through app

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Backbonejs total newbie here, and really overall a rookie in developing applications this way.  I have a view that renders HTML with some jQuery code that allows a set of fields to be replicated.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
        currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
        newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

    // Reset the entries to the newly added field.
    newEntry.find('#title').val('');
    newEntry.find('#section').val('');
    newEntry.find('#active').prop('checked',false);

    controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
        .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
        .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
        .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span>');

}).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e){
    $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

I have some other jQuery that iterates through a JSON object (loaded into a js variable in the view) - and triggers the "click" event and assigns the values to the form elements.

```
var d = '<%= sections %>';

if (d) {
    var cnt = 0;
    $.each($.parseJSON(d), function() {
        if (cnt >=1) {
            $('.btn-add').trigger('click');
        }
        cnt++;
    });

    var t = $.parseJSON(d);
    cnt = 0;
    $('#sections *').filter(':input').each(function(){
        if (this.name) {
            if (this.type == "checkbox") {
                if (t[cnt][this.name]) {
                    $(this).prop('checked', true);
                } else {
                    $(this).prop('checked', false);
                }
            } else {
                $(this).val(t[cnt][this.name]);
            }
        } else {
            // button element has no name, so this is the end of this set of fields.
            // increment counter here
            cnt++
        }
    });
}
```

Everything works great on the first load of this.  Or a "reload".  But as I navigate through the Backbonejs application - the view totally fails.  This is how it looks on a fresh load:

[image: Correctly rendered with data from model]

A second load (notice the + sign is gone, and there is an extra fieldset).

[image: Second Load after navigating around app]

One interesting thing; when the "+" is clicked, it should only replicate the fieldset once.  But after navigating around the application - it will be replicated several times (depending on how many times I click other links and then back to the "sections" link). My instinct is the whole view is being re-created and the listeners are replicating for each reload.  Is this right, and if so - how can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Also thought I'd mention that there are no errors displayed in Chrome javascript console.

Comment: You said backbone... I couldn't find a single backbone object in that code... Am i missing something..?

Comment: it's broken, 404 error

Comment: Try this link (https://gist.github.com/ajkreitman/315b94cd6f844a68c293)

Comment: Here's a link to my app.js file where the view is instantiated: (https://gist.github.com/ajkreitman/8848a243f624def45678)

Comment: Where are applying listeners, so it gets duplicated?, please show the code more properly

Comment: I believe I'm not asking the question in a way that makes sense.  It seems like the backbone view is not being properly removed when navigating around the app.   The behavior I'm seeing makes me think that the jquery code `$(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)` is being applied over and over again.  I apologize for not providing enough detail.  I have the view, template, and call at this URL (https://gist.github.com/ajkreitman)